# Display array in view / controller codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I dont have the same result when i var_dump an array in my controller and in my view. This is my controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $getFestivals = $this->festival_model->getAllFestivals();
    if (!empty($getFestivals)) {
        foreach ($getFestivals as $festival) {
            $countFestivalEdition = $this->festival_model->countFestivalEditionByFestivalID($festival->fID);
            $festival->fCountEdition = $countFestivalEdition;
        }
    }

    $this->data['getFestivals'] = $getFestivals;
    @var_dump($this->data['getFestivals']);die;
    $this->render_layout('festivals/index', $this->data);
}
```

The var_dump (juste before last line) return me:

```
      0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'fID' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'fName' => string 'Festival2' (length=17)
      public 'fPicture' => string '3df2c152d9dec657380c53b679d0b92b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'fCity' => string 'City2' (length=9)
      public 'fCountry' => string 'France' (length=6)
      public 'fCountEdition' => int 2
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'fID' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'fName' => string 'Festival1' (length=19)
      public 'fPicture' => string '73a267e6c047d507b66b3a1ab1fc0059.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'fCity' => string 'City1' (length=16)
      public 'fCountry' => string 'France' (length=6)
      public 'fCountEdition' => int 1
```

On this var_dump i have my 'fCountEdition'. When i make var_dump on my view, i have this (var_dump($getFestivals);die;):

```
      0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'fID' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'fName' => string 'Festival2' (length=17)
      public 'fPicture' => string '3df2c152d9dec657380c53b679d0b92b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'fCity' => string 'City2' (length=9)
      public 'fCountry' => string 'France' (length=6)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'fID' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'fName' => string 'Festival1' (length=19)
      public 'fPicture' => string '73a267e6c047d507b66b3a1ab1fc0059.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'fCity' => string 'City1' (length=16)
      public 'fCountry' => string 'France' (length=6)
```

**Why he dont parse my data fCountEdition ?**

For informations, my render_layout look like this:
$this->load->view($view, $this->data);

Comment: send me your model code

Answer (score 0):

You may try this simple way to send array to view as give example bellow.

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {       
        $data=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
        $result=$data->result_array();

        $headerData = array(
        "pageTitle" => "Home",
        "stylesheet" => array("home.css")
    );
    $footerData = array(
        "jsFiles" => array("home.js")
    );
    $viewData = array(
        "viewName" => "home",
        "viewData" => array('result'=>$result),
        "headerData" => $headerData,
        "footerData" => $footerData 
    );
    //Sendig all Result Data to view by Storing into array as $result
    $this->load->view('template',$viewData);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 

   var_dump($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not referencing `$getFestivals`, instead you are passing the value of it to `$festival` and trying to assign it a new variable.

Basically, passing the value allows you to 'copy' the array/object/etc without modifying the original.

Referencing the original allows to to modify it directly from within the loop.

Do do it the way you've written the code, you need to reference the original instead.

```
foreach ($getFestivals as &$festival) {   <-- add ampersand before $
        $countFestivalEdition = $this->festival_model->countFestivalEditionByFestivalID($festival->fID);
        $festival->fCountEdition = $countFestivalEdition;
    }
```